# Nginx docker (13: Permission denied) while logging request to mounted volume

Tags: logging, nginx, docker, permissions, mounted-volumes

I am using nginx version: nginx/1.11.8

My docker file looks like:

```
FROM nginx
COPY website /usr/share/nginx/html/website/
RUN chown -R nginx /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN chown -R nginx /var/log/nginx/
EXPOSE 80
```

I am using variables for my access log names as shown below.  When running without mounting to a directory on the host machine this works fine and the logs are produced.

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") { set $year $1; set $month $2; set $day $3; }
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.$hostname.$year-$month-$day.log logs;
}
```

My host log directory is owner:steve group:logs

if i remove the variables from the access log name then it logs correctly to the host directory i.e

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.novars.log logs;
```

Am i missing something glaringly obvious to get this to work using variables ?

Comment: Lines 4 and 5 are giving permissions to the same place for a different owner, Is this by intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the if statement inside location block causing the issue.  This works and allows me to rotate my logfiles by date.

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/conf/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

server {
  listen       80 default_server;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  underscores_in_headers on;

  if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") { set $year $1; set $month $2; set $day $3; }

    location / {
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$query_string;
      access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.agent-ux.$hostname.$year-$month-$day.log logs;
    }
  }
}
```